# HOW To get monthwise report of downloaded songs of last 1 year from current date in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I want to get no of downloads per month from current date since last 1 year

This is my query

```
SELECT a.imei, 
       a.numberofdownloads, 
       a.numberofdownloads AS aug, 
       a.numberofstreams   AS jul, 
       a.numberofdownloads AS jun, 
       a.numberofstreams, 
       b.datetime 
FROM   activeusers a, 
       imei_downloadstream b 
WHERE  a.imei = b.imei 
       AND b.datetime BETWEEN Date_format(Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 month, 
                              '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00' 
                              ) AND 
                                  Date_format(Last_day(Curdate() - 
                                                       INTERVAL 1 month), 
                                  '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') 
       AND Date_format(Last_day(Curdate() - INTERVAL 2 month), 
           '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') 
       AND Date_format(Last_day(Curdate() - INTERVAL 3 month), 
           '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') 
LIMIT  10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You need a way to determine the first day of the month from the current date.

You have almost figured that out. It is this:

```
DATE(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'))
```

Then you need to use a `GROUP BY` clause featuring that expression. Something like this will do it.

```
SELECT  a.imei, 
        SUM(a.numberofdownloads) AS numberofdownloads,
        DATE(DATE_FORMAT(b.datetime, '%Y-%m-01')) AS month_beginning 
 FROM   activeusers a, 
 JOIN   imei_downloadstream b ON a.imei = b.imei 
WHERE   b.datetime >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')) - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
  AND   b.datetime <  DATE(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')) 
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(b.datetime, '%Y-%m-01')), a.imei
```

See what's going on here? You're choosing all the records having dates between the first of the month twelve months ago and the first of the present month. Then you're computing the beginning date of the month for each record, then you're grouping by that value.

This works flawlessly if you get your JOIN right.  Here is a more detailed writelup.

http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/